# common services in asp.net core with razor pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

For reference, I have a common `BasePageModel` which inherits `PageModel`.

I also have several services I will ALWAYS use:

1. `UserManager<AppUser> userManager`
2. `IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor`
3. `IHostingEnvironment env`

Is there a way to ALWAYS inject these so that I do not have to do constructor injection for each of these services on every single Razor Page?

Comment: You don’t need to use the context accessor at all since you have access to the `HttpContext` from both MVC controllers and page models. As for user manager and hosting environment, no, you will have to inject those properly. But if you see yourself using them that often, you should consider moving some logic out of your page model. If you explain what you are actually doing, we might be able to suggest alternative ways.

Comment: @poke thanks for the quick response!  On each razor page, I typically will need to access something from `HttpContext` and determine if the page is being loaded in development or production.  Seems like ALWAYS injecting them isn't really DRY.

Comment: What are you using that information for though? To show alternative things? Maybe you could move that logic elsewhere (e.g. in tag helpers, like the `<environment>` tag helper which already exists). And usually having all dependencies listed explicitly is considered a good style even if it feels redundant or boilerplate-y.

Comment: @poke Yes for showing alternative things or not executing code in certain situations.  For instance, in development / testing, I will not want to send result and confirmation emails on form submissions.  I will look into the environment tag helper.  thanks for that!

Comment: *“in development / testing, I will not want to send result and confirmation emails on form submissions”* – Consider abstracting that into services then. For example, instead of sending the email directly from your page model, have some email service that is responsible for sending the mails. You can then either skip sending out the mails within that service, or completely swap out the service implementation during development. So the page model does not have to have this responsibility and stays the same regardless of environment.

Comment: Interesting @poke.  I already have the email service but did not think about the 'swap out' idea.  Hmm.  This may be means for another question on SO, but by default, in development I would not want to send those emails.  However, in some cases when testing the email service in particular, I would want to send emails in development but ONLY to the testing email addresses (just me).  How would you handle this scenario?

Comment: Usually, you would have a SMTP server for testing there that would be configured to trap all outgoing emails and forward them to some internal inbox. That way you can verify that your application works correctly (without regards to the current configured environment) and at the same time be safe against accidental emails leaving your development stage.

Comment: Go grab Papercut (https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut). Then just use config to set your dev SMTP connection to localhost:25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can define a service to be injected into every view using `_ViewImports.cshtml`. Just add your view injection there, and the service will be available to every view.

However, you should not do that with any of the three services you explicitly mention. First, `IHttpContextAccessor` is unnecessary as you can get the `HttpContext` in your view via `ViewContext.HttpContext`. Likewise, `IHostingEnvironment` is mostly unnecessary as well, since you can use the `environment` tag helper:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <p>This is development.</p>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <p>This is production.</p>
</environment>
```

For `UserManager<AppUser>`, it's better to only include such a service when you truly need it. If you find yourself doing the same logic over and over requiring this service, consider creating a tag helper or a view component instead to encapsulate that logic in a way that you can use it in multiple places without having to inject anything special into your view.

Finally, since the main point of this discussion was mostly about not sending email in development, the better approach there is to simply swap out the SMTP server with a something local in development. There's an app called [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut) which is open-source and free and makes sending/receiving email in development a breeze. By default, it will bind to localhost:25, so you'll just need to swap out your real SMTP connection with that. For example, you can create a section in your your appsettings.json like:

```
"Smtp": {
  "Host": "localhost",
  "Port": 25,
  "EnableSsl": false,
  "Username": "",
  "Password": ""
}
```

Then, in your startup:

```
services.AddSingleton(_ => {
    var config = Configuration.GetSection("Smtp").Get<SmtpConfig>();
    return new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = config.Host,
        Port = config.Port,
        EnableSsl = config.EnableSsl,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password)
    };
});
```

Then, simply inject `SmtpClient` into your email service, and you're off to the races. In production, you can use environment variables or Azure Key Vault to swap in your production SMTP connection settings. It's best not to use appsettings.json (or appsettings.Production.json) for this, as you'll most likely not want to commit it into your source control.